# How do I create a delete/clear button in REACT js?

Tags: reactjs

Hi I'm new to REACT and I have a HW where I need to create a grocery shopping list and I need to create a clear button. The isPurchased key value pair is a boolean though. I need to create a button that when I click Purchased it clears that grocery item off my list. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class App extends Component {
state = {
grocery: grocery,
item: '',
brand: '',
units: Number,
quantity: Number,
isPurchased: Boolean
}

handleChange = (e) => {
this.setState({ [e.target.id]: e.target.value })
}

handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault()


const addGrocery = {
  item: this.state.item,
  brand: this.state.brand,
  units: this.state.units,
  quantity: this.state.quantity,

}
this.setState({
  grocery: [addGrocery, ...this.state.grocery],
  item: '',
  brand: '',
  units: Number,
  quantity: Number,
})

const removeGrocery = {
  item: this.state.item
}
```

}

Comment: you need to add your code into the question, then people can help

Comment: How to ask a good question at stackoverflow, please read the guide - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=geocery+list+tutorial+react&oq=geocery+list+tutorial+react&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i10i160l2j33i22i29i30l2.12509j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: {!isPurchased && <GroceryItem />}

Answer (score 0):

hey here is a full code for creating a to do list in react (it will be very similar to your problem):

**

- Summary

** of the idea of creating a to-do list or shopping list is that each to-do will be an object, when we create a new object we will insert it into an array. once it is in the array by using the array.map() function we will convert each object to an HTML element to make the UI.

if something is unclear I am here to answer

file - App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useReducer } from "react";
import Todo from "./Todo";

export const ACTIONS = {
  ADD_TODO: "add-todo",
  TOGGLE_TODO: "toggle-todo",
  DELETE_TODO: "delete-todo",
};

function reducer(todos, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.ADD_TODO:
      return [...todos, newTodo(action.payload.name)];
    case ACTIONS.TOGGLE_TODO:
      return todos.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.id === action.payload.id) {
          return { ...todo, complete: !todo.complete }; //change to complete if we found to id that toggled
        }
        return todo;
      });
    case ACTIONS.DELETE_TODO:
      return todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== action.payload.id);
    default:
      return todos;
  }
}

function newTodo(name) {
  return { id: Date.now(), name: name, complete: false };
}

const App = () => {
  const [todos, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []); //useReducer return the state and the reducer function
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.ADD_TODO, payload: { name: name } });
    setName("");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
      </form>
      {todos.map((todo) => {
        return <Todo key={todo.id} todo={todo} dispatch={dispatch} />;
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Another file (component) - Todo.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { ACTIONS } from "./App";

const Todo = ({ todo, dispatch }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span style={{ color: todo.complete ? "#AAA" : "#000" }}>
        {todo.name}
      </span>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.TOGGLE_TODO, payload: { id: todo.id } })
        }
      >
        Toggle
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.DELETE_TODO, payload: { id: todo.id } })
        }
      >
        Delete
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Todo;
```

Comment: I'm using the handle change